# Regex select previous occurence

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract the City element of from string having the following format:

```
<BR>Address 1<BR>Address 2<BR>City<BR>A1A 0A0<BR>Phone Number <BR>
```

OR

```
<BR>Address 1<BR>Address 2<BR>Address 3<BR>City<BR>A1A 0A0<BR>Phone Number <BR>
```

The input string can have a random number of Address item before the city.

So far, my strategy is to select the postal code (A1A 0A0) and then extract the previous record using `<BR>` as marker.

So far I am using

```
<BR>(.*)<BR>[ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ] [0-9][ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]
$1
```

Where $1 return the first group of regex in the tool I am using (visual web ripper). However the expression returns everything before the postal code.

So is there a way to make a regex non greedy to select the previous occurence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So bear with me on this one, but [this is how](http://regex101.com/r/cB8jV2) I got it to work:

```
(?:<BR>(.*?))+<BR>[ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ] [0-9][ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]
```

Explanation:

```
(?:       # Start a non-capturing group (so that we don't have unnecessary matches)
  <BR>    # Look for a <BR> to start the group
  (.*?)   # Then lazily match 0+ characters (lazy will stop us at the next match)
)+        # End the group and repeat it 1+ times (each field)
<BR>      # Look for one final <BR> right before the Zip Code
[...]     # I didn't feel like including the Zip Code logic you wrote :)
```

However, depending on your language, I would recommend splitting the string and looping through it.  Example in PHP:

```
$pieces = explode('<BR>', '<BR>Address 1<BR>Address 2<BR>Address 3<BR>City<BR>A1A 0A0<BR>Phone Number<BR>');
$count = count($pieces);

$city = null;
for($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
    if(preg_match('/[ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ] [0-9][ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]/', $pieces[$i])) {
        $city = $pieces[$i - 1];
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($city);
// string(4) "City"
```

Answer (score 1):

Took me  a bit to get it but here:

```
[^>]*<BR>[ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ] [0-9][ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]
```

Edit: If you want to add capturing or non-capturing group you can do the following:

Non-capturing for the 
 and Postal Code:

```
[^>]*(?:<BR>[ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ] [0-9][ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9])
```

Capturing for just the city:

```
([^>]*)<BR>[ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ] [0-9][ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]
```

Edit 2:

As per comments below: Will only work if the name of the city does not contain the ">" character

Comment: I almost went this approach, but it would fail if the city contained `>` (which is unlikely, yes).

Comment: Oh, I presumed that the city name would not contain the > character

Comment: Probably a valid assumption, just wanted to make the note for OP :)

Comment: Yep good to you for pointing it out, I forgot to specify this in my answer.

Comment: Hopefully city would not contains `>` but we never know! Thanks all expression works great! I accepted the other answer for the detailled explanation.